# Attach new object array to current

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular 6 project which gets some data on `ngOnInit()` from backend API. On a second separate call, the API returns a second package of data.

The first and the second data package look the same, like this:

```
 [ 
   { 
     title: "Demo Titel",
     teaser: "Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa Fooo"
   }, 
   {
     title: "Demo Titel 2",
     teaser: "Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa 222 Fooo"
   },
   {…},
   {…},
   {…}, 
 ]
```

So now I want to put the second data package, which looks complete same, in front of the first data.

I have tried to do this with `...` operators and `concat()` but these opportunities always just put the second data after the first, and not in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that array1 is coming before array 2 as follows:

```
var array1 = ["item 1", "item 2"];
var array2 = ["item 3", "item 4", "item 5"];
return array1.concat(array2);
```

Could you reverse how you are using concat

```
return array2.concat(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the spread operator. The key is the placement of the `...` with the second/new set of data. You'd need to place it at the beginning of the array to prepend it.

```
this.existingItems = [...newItems, ...this.existingItems];
```

```js
const foo = [ 
   { 
     title: "Demo Tite 1",
     teaser: "Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa Fooo"
   }, 
   {
     title: "Demo Titel 2",
     teaser: "Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa 222 Fooo"
   }
 ];
 
 const bar = [ 
   { 
     title: "Demo Titel 3",
     teaser: "Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz Foo Bar Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa Fooo"
   }, 
   {
     title: "Demo Titel 4",
     teaser: "Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz 2 Foo 2 Bar 2 Baz",
     otherStuff: "Blaa 222 Fooo"
   }
 ];
 
 const baz = [...bar, ...foo];
 
 console.log(baz);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` as you wanted, and it will merge arrays in the same order, as you passed them inside `concat` method. In this example I log 2 orders - *arr1 -> arr2* and *arr2 -> arr1*:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    prop1: "ONE Value 1",
    prop2: "ONE Value 2"
  },
  {
    prop1: "ONE Value 1",
    prop2: "ONE Value 2"
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    prop1: "TWO Value 1",
    prop2: "TWO Value 2"
  },
  {
    prop1: "TWO Value 1",
    prop2: "TWO Value 2"
  }
];

console.log([].concat(arr1, arr2)); // The order is: arr1, arr2
console.log([].concat(arr2, arr1)); // The order is: arr2, arr1
```